# Segmentation fault in debug only for templated class

Tags: c++, exception, segmentation-fault

I am following an Udemy C++20 Course.

I have a templated class CBoxContainer that has a segmentation fault in Debug only but not in release.

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class CBoxContainer {

    static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<T>, L"Types contained in CBoxContainer shall be default constructible");

public:

    explicit CBoxContainer<T>(const size_t capacity = defaultCapacityConstexpr);
    CBoxContainer<T>(const CBoxContainer<T>& source);
    CBoxContainer<T>(CBoxContainer<T>&& source);
    ~CBoxContainer<T>(); 

    void Add(const T& item);
 //  void Add(const T&& item); if we'd do so, it will never work because we have to invalidate input parameters
 //and that means changing them
    void Add(T&& item);
    bool Remove(const T& item);
    size_t RemoveAll(const T& item);

    void operator+=(const CBoxContainer<T>& operand);
    void operator=(const CBoxContainer<T>& source);
    void operator=(CBoxContainer<T>&& source);

    void Print() const;

    size_t GetSize() const;
    size_t GetCapacity() const;
    T* GetMax() const;

    const T* Get(const size_t index) const;
    T* Get(const size_t index);

    bool ModifyElement(const size_t index, const T newValue);
    static void SetVerbose(const bool verbosity);

    static constexpr auto defaultCapacityConstexpr = 4;


protected:
    static bool isVerbose;
    void Expand(const size_t newCapacity);
    void Invalidate();

    T* m_pItems = nullptr;
    size_t m_capacity = defaultCapacityConstexpr;
    size_t m_size = 0;
   

};

template<typename T>
inline bool CBoxContainer<T>::isVerbose = false;

template<typename T>
CBoxContainer<T>::CBoxContainer(const size_t capacity) : m_pItems(new T[capacity]), m_capacity(capacity), m_size(0)
{
    std::cout << "Called default constructor at address " << this << "\n";
}

template<typename T>
CBoxContainer<T>::CBoxContainer(const CBoxContainer<T>& source) : m_pItems(new T[source.m_capacity]), m_capacity(source.m_capacity), m_size(source.m_size)
{
    if (CBoxContainer<T>::isVerbose)
    {
        std::cout << "Calling Copy Constructor at address " << this << ", copying " << source.GetSize() << " elements" << "\n";
    }
    memcpy(m_pItems, source.m_pItems, source.m_size * sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
CBoxContainer<T>::CBoxContainer(CBoxContainer<T>&& source)
{
    if (CBoxContainer<T>::isVerbose)
    {
        std::cout << "Calling Move Constructor at address" << this << "\n";
    }

    if (this == &source)
    {
        return;
    }

    m_pItems = source.m_pItems;
    m_capacity = source.m_capacity;
    m_size = source.m_size;
   
    source.Invalidate();
}

template<typename T>
CBoxContainer<T>::~CBoxContainer()
{
    if (CBoxContainer<T>::isVerbose)
    {
        std::cout << "Destroying CBoxContainer at address " << this << "\n";
        if (m_pItems != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "Deleting pointer " << m_pItems << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Deleting null pointer \n";
        }
    }
    delete []m_pItems;
    m_pItems = nullptr;
}



template<typename T>
void CBoxContainer<T>::Add(const T& item)
{
    if (m_size + 1 > m_capacity)
    {
        Expand((m_size + 1) * 2);
    }

    m_pItems[m_size++] = item;
}

template<typename T>
void CBoxContainer<T>::Add(T&& item)
{
    if (m_size + 1 > m_capacity)
    {
        Expand((m_size + 1) * 2);
    }

    //m_pItems[m_size++] = item; if we would so, we would have a copy assignment and not a move assigment
    m_pItems[m_size++] = std::move(item);
}
template<typename T>
bool CBoxContainer<T>::Remove(const T& item)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
    {
        if (m_pItems[i] == item)
        {
            for (size_t j = i + 1; j < m_size; j++)
            {
                m_pItems[i] = m_pItems[j];
                
            }
            m_size--;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


template<typename T>
size_t CBoxContainer<T>::RemoveAll(const T& item)
{
    size_t removedElements = 0;
    while (Remove(item)) {
        ++removedElements;
    }
    return removedElements;
}

template<typename T>
void CBoxContainer<T>::Expand(const size_t newCapacity)
{
    auto newPointer = new T[newCapacity];
    memcpy(newPointer, m_pItems, m_size * sizeof(T));
    delete []m_pItems;
    m_pItems = newPointer;
    m_capacity = newCapacity;
}

template<typename T>
void CBoxContainer<T>::operator+=(const CBoxContainer<T>& operand)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < operand.m_size; i++)
    {
        Add(operand.m_pItems[i]);
    }
}

template<typename T>
void CBoxContainer<T>::operator=(const CBoxContainer<T>& source)
{
    if (this == std::addressof(source))
    {
        if (CBoxContainer<T>::isVerbose)
        {
            std::cout << "Skipping copy assignment, same container";
        }
        return;
    }


    if (CBoxContainer<T>::isVerbose)
    {
        std::cout << "Callying assignment operator with " << source.GetSize() << " elements \n";
    }
    if (source.m_size > m_capacity)
    {
        Expand(source.m_size);
    }
    m_capacity = source.m_capacity;
    m_size = source.m_size;
    memcpy(m_pItems, source.m_pItems, m_size * sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
void CBoxContainer<T>::operator=(CBoxContainer<T>&& source)
{
    if (this == std::addressof(source))
    {
        std::cout << "Skipping move assignment, same address";
        return;
    }
    if (CBoxContainer<T>::isVerbose)
    {
        std::cout << "Calling Move Assignment\n";
    }

    if (this == &source)
    {
        return;
    }

    m_pItems = source.m_pItems;
    m_capacity = source.m_capacity;
    m_size = source.m_size;

    source.Invalidate();
}

template<typename T>
inline size_t CBoxContainer<T>::GetSize() const
{
    return m_size;
}

template<typename T>
inline size_t CBoxContainer<T>::GetCapacity() const
{
    return m_capacity;
}

template<typename T>
inline const T* CBoxContainer<T>::Get(const size_t index) const
{
    return index < m_size ? std::addressof(m_pItems[index]) : nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
inline T* CBoxContainer<T>::Get(const size_t index)
{
    return index < m_size ? std::addressof(m_pItems[index]) : nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
inline bool CBoxContainer<T>::ModifyElement(const size_t index, const T newValue)
{
    auto pElement = this->Get(index);
    if (pElement == nullptr)
    {
        return false;
    }

    m_pItems[index] = newValue;
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
void CBoxContainer<T>::SetVerbose(const bool verbosity)
{
    CBoxContainer<T>::isVerbose = verbosity;
}

template<typename T>
void CBoxContainer<T>::Invalidate()
{
    m_pItems = nullptr;
    m_size = 0;
    m_capacity = 0;
}


template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const CBoxContainer<T>& operand)
{
    const auto operandSize = operand.GetSize();
    out << "Printing container at address " << std::addressof(operand) << " with size " << operandSize << ", capacity " << operand.GetCapacity() << " :\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < operandSize; i++)
    {
        out << i << ": " << " " << *operand.Get(i) << "\n";
    }
    return out;
}

template<typename T>
inline T*  CBoxContainer<T>::GetMax() const
{
    if (m_size == 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    auto pMaximum = std::addressof(m_pItems[0]);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < this->GetSize(); i++)
    {
        auto currentPointer = std::addressof(m_pItems[i]);
        pMaximum = currentPointer != nullptr && *currentPointer > *pMaximum ? currentPointer: pMaximum;
    }

    return pMaximum;
}
```

The code that actually uses this class is this one:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "../../Internal/BoxContainer.hpp"




constexpr int shiftConstexpr = 3;



char Encrypt489(const char& param)
{
    return static_cast<char>(param + shiftConstexpr);
}

char Decrypt489(const char& param)
{
    return static_cast<char>(param - shiftConstexpr);
}

typedef char (*CodecCallBack) (const char&);


std::string Modify(const std::string& baseString, CodecCallBack callback)
{
    std::string returnString{ baseString };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < returnString.size(); i++)
    {
        auto& currentElement = returnString[i];
        currentElement = callback(currentElement);
    }
    return std::move(returnString);
}


CBoxContainer<std::string> Modify(const CBoxContainer<std::string>& inputBox, CodecCallBack callback)
{
    //just these two lines makes program crash, even if not encoding/decoding single characters
    auto newContainer = CBoxContainer<std::string>(inputBox);
    return newContainer;
}




int main()
{
    auto TestSingleCharacters = []()
    {
        std::cout << "A encrypted : " << Encrypt489('A') << "\n";
        std::cout << "D decrypted : " << Decrypt489('D') << "\n";
        std::cout << "A roundtrip : " << Decrypt489(Encrypt489('A')) << "\n";
        std::cout << "A inverse roundtrip : " << Encrypt489(Decrypt489('A')) << "\n";

        auto result = 'D' == Encrypt489('A');
        result &= 'A' == Decrypt489('D');
        result &= 'A' == Decrypt489(Encrypt489('A'));
        result &= 'A' == Encrypt489(Decrypt489('A'));
     
        return result;
    };

    auto TestString = []()
    {
        std::string hello{ "Hello" };
        std::string expectedHelloEncryption{ "Khoor" };
        std::cout << hello << " encrypted: " << Modify(hello, Encrypt489) << "\n";
        std::cout << expectedHelloEncryption << " decyrpted: " << Modify(expectedHelloEncryption, Decrypt489) << "\n";
        std::cout << hello << " roundtrip: " << Modify(Modify(hello, Encrypt489), Decrypt489) << "\n";
        std::cout << hello << " inverse roundtrip: " << Modify(Modify(hello, Decrypt489), Encrypt489) << "\n";
        

        auto result = expectedHelloEncryption == Modify(hello, Encrypt489);
        result &= hello == Modify(expectedHelloEncryption, Decrypt489);
        result &= hello == Modify(Modify(hello, Encrypt489), Decrypt489);
        result &= hello == Modify(Modify(hello, Decrypt489), Encrypt489);

        return result;
    };

    
    //Not working and I do not know why
    auto TestBox = []()
    {
        CBoxContainer<std::string>::SetVerbose(true);
        CBoxContainer<std::string> stringBox;;

        stringBox.Add("A");

        std::cout << stringBox << "\n";

        std::cout << "Encryption: " << Modify(stringBox, Encrypt489) << "\n";

        return true;
    };



    auto result = TestSingleCharacters() && TestString() && TestBox();
    return 0;
}
```

It fails due to `_CONSTEXPR20 void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all_unlocked_v3() noexcept` rasining an exception but just in debug, not in release.

Instrumented code (and debugging) show no double deletion:

```
Called default constructor at address 0000005E56CFEC58
Printing container at address 0000005E56CFEC58 with size 1, capacity 4 :
0:  A

Encryption: Calling Copy Constructor at address 0000005E56CFEB08, copying 1 elements
Calling Move Constructor at address0000005E56CFED88
Destroying CBoxContainer at address 0000005E56CFEB08
Deleting null pointer
Printing container at address 0000005E56CFED88 with size 1, capacity 4 :
0:  A

Destroying CBoxContainer at address 0000005E56CFED88
Deleting pointer 000001FC01A4A868
Destroying CBoxContainer at address 0000005E56CFEC58
Deleting pointer 000001FC01A4A778
```

So actually I didn't either use the simple "encrypt/decrypt" methods for characters, just calling that subroutine made my program crash, but why?

Comment: A segmentation fault is basically always a case of accessing invalid memory. It not appearing in a release build just means that the *undefined behavior* manifests differently (e.g.: because the compiler removed checks that it had inserted in a debug build)

Comment: Using `memcpy` with `std::string`s and other not Trivially Copyable types has undefined behaviour.

Comment: did you read and understand all warnings? https://godbolt.org/z/aj4bG18qa I admit I dont understand all, but some sound rather "interesting" (btw I had to add `#include <cstring>` to get it compile)

Comment: Looking at some things, this course doesn't appear to be great.

Comment: Instead of `memcpy` you should be using `std::copy` or a manual loop over the array indices. `memcpy` should only be used in very specialized circumstances that don't apply to generic types like you are using here.

Comment: Works by iterating by array indices, i.e.     'for (size_t i = 0; i < source.m_size; i++)
    {
        m_pItems[i] = source.m_pItems[i];
    }'

instead of memcpy